# Replace specific part of a string with specific conditions in vba

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I am trying to replace specific part of the string with blank.

For example my column has a value `"I LOVE 10 IN20 records from INDIA"` – here, I need to replace `(Space)IN` with Only `‘IN’`. i.e `I LOVE 10IN20 records from INDIA`.
I tried available replace function, it is replacing (Space)INDIA as well, which should not happen in my case.

*Correct Output* : `I LOVE 10IN20 records from INDIA`

*Wrong Output*   : `I LOVE 10IN20 records fromINDIA`

I have tried vba function like below . Still it won’t consider’s the space(that’s the issue I am getting here)

```
Function MyReplace(AddressLine As String, FullName As String, Abbrev As String)
MyReplace = Trim(Replace(" " & AddressLine & " ", _
                                  " " & FullName & " ", _
                                  " " & Abbrev & " "))
End Function
```

**I'm trying to write a VBA function in Access**, Can anyone help with the pattern matching as in the above examples?

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks for only one specific example: `"I LOVE 10 IN20 records from INDIA"`

```
Correct Output: I LOVE 10IN20 records from INDIA

Wrong Output:   I LOVE 10IN20 records fromINDIA
```

---

The solution for that particular case:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceSpace()

    Dim s As String

    s = "I LOVE 10 IN20 records from INDIA"

    s = Replace(s, "10 ", "10")

    Debug.Print s   'I LOVE 10IN20 records from INDIA

End Sub
```

---

If you have other cases you should provide them, or provide the exact pattern for replacement

Comment: Space N needs to be replaced, Not Space N[0-9a-z]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you define your task & the business logic. With the info you have given, `LTrim()` would work quite well, considring that you give also a space after the `IN` as an input:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim strInput As String
    strInput = "I LOVE 10 IN 20 records from INDIA"
    Debug.Print MyReplace(strInput, " IN ")    
End Sub

Function MyReplace(strInput As String, replaceOnly As String) As String
    MyReplace = Replace(strInput, replaceOnly, LTrim(replaceOnly))
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.. But i want it to remove only space N, not Space N Space.. Your code does not work for this input "I LOVE 10 IN20 records from INDIA", Please check and let me know possible code

Comment: Output should be : I LOVE 10IN20 records from INDIA

Comment: that is where my logic is lagging, please help with the code.

Comment: @natwarlal - in my answer, replace `LTrim` with `Trim` and it will work.

Comment: still it is giving wrong output, can you modify the code and show here please

Comment: @natwarlal - literally, remove the `L` from `LTrim`, nothing else.

Comment: still same output

Comment: @natwarlal - restart your PC and try again.